# Issue in ionic2 tutorial template project

Tags: ionic2

I am getting below error when I tried to run the ionic tutorial project created by using **ionic start MyIonic2ProjectSideMenu tutorial --v2**

Could someone help me how to fix this issue.

> >
>   node_modules/ionic-angular/components.core.scss
>   Error: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
>           on line 34 of node_modules/ionic-angular/components.core.scss
>      @import "fonts/ionicons";
>      --^

Comment: could you please let us know what version of Ionic you use..?

Comment: 2.0.0-beta.25 @RajaYogan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been recently fixed, try updating to the latest beta6 and generating a new project.